# how i can iterate over a column (type : series)

Tags: python, pandas

i want to iterate over rows of a column (type : series), each row represents a series of words, and i want to classify each word.

examples of some rows:

```
['hard', 'house', 'warm', 'lovely']


['beauty', morning', 'work', 'sick']
```

i have the following code :

```
for i, row in df['splitsent'].items(): 

    test=i['splitsent']
```

i get this error :

```
' test_set=i['stoplist']


TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable '
```

Comment: Could you please add the desired output

Comment: the desired output is : 
{'hard' : 'neg', 'house':'neu', 'warm':'pos', 'lovely':'pos'}
{'beauty':'pos', morning':'neu', 'work':'neu', 'sick':'neg'}

i defined positive and negative features, train_set and a function wich returns dictionaries and it works. but in this level of the code, i want to define each row ( series) as a test_set

Answer (score 1):

This is `iterrows`

```
for x , y in df.iterrows(): 

    print(x)#index
    print(y)#serise row
```

If that is series

```
for x,y in zip(df.index,df.Value):#df.Value.iterrows()
    print(x)#index
    print(y)#value
```

Comment: `Series` has `iteritems` for index, value

Answer (score 0):

row is the data. i is the integer index: 0, 1, 2, ...  so

```
i['splitsent']
```

does not make sense for an integer, i.

Comment: what i wanted to do is that each row will be ranked: row1 ['splitsent'], row2 ['splitsent'], so this is why i put i ['splitsent']